The dimension of local rings of the formal schemes
The problem comes from Hartshorne's  Algebraic Geometry, II, Remark 9.3.1. Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme, and $Y$ be a closed subscheme defined by a sheaf of ideals $\mathscr{J}$. Let $\hat{X}$ be the formal completion of $X$ along $Y$. Then Hartshorne claims that the local rings of $\hat{X}$ has dimension $\dim X$. How to prove it?
We may discuss at a point $x \in U = \operatorname{Spec} A$, an open affine subset of $X$. Regard $x$ as a prime in $A$, I know that $\mathscr{O}_{\hat{X}, x} = \varinjlim A_{\{f\}}$, $f \notin x$. But I am not sure how to show $\dim \mathscr{O}_{\hat{X}, x} = \dim X$ or $\dim A$.
